# array and stucture with textfile

Tags: c++, arrays, ifstream

try to put a text file in an array with a structure Students (FirstName) but it put

> error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Students' (or there is no acceptable conversion)))

```
Students stud[15];
ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("student.txt");
for (int i = 0; i<14; i++)
{
    myfile >> stud[i];
    cout << stud[i] << endl;
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: what part of error message is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Students class constructor it looks like you are making a variable to hold their first name, so when adding it to the text file you would have to call on that variable, not the entire Student object.

```
myFile >> stud[i].firstName;
```

Where firstName is the name of whatever variable holds FirstName from the Student constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, `Students` lacks io stream overloads. You will have to write them.

```
class Students
{
    //rest of Students definition
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Students & val)
    {
        out << val.firstMember << " " << val.secondMember << " " << ... << '\n';
    }
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, const Students & val)
    {
        std::string line;
        if (std::getline(in, line))
        {
            std::stringstream linestream(line);
            if (! linestream >> val.firstMember >> val.secondMember >> ...)
            {
                 // handle error?
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Note: More brains and smarter delimiters may be required depending on the needs of your output format.